# DB Restore : Property MasterDBPath is not available for Information 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Information'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to restore my sql db using a .bak file.
This bak file was created on some other machine.

When i try to restore in sql management studio. I get following error.

**Property MasterDBPath is not available for Information 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Information'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)**

Don't know where the problem is?

Is it in the backup file or something wrong with sql management studio?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed after I installed the newest Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017